# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Issue with closing a Window in macOS Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

This codes works well until I want close about window with mouse or using keyboard with `command + w`, when I close my about window an Error happen:

Error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

Not sure why this error happen and how to solve the issue! By the way I am using a main file for loading my app like this:

```
import Cocoa

// **** Main **** //
let nsApplication = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
nsApplication.delegate = appDelegate
nsApplication.run()
```

And this is my all codes:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private var window: NSWindow!
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        buildMainMenu()
        
        buildWindow()
        
    }
    
    func buildWindow() {
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
    }
    
    func buildMainMenu() {
        
        let appMainMenu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        
        let mainMenu: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        mainMenu.submenu = NSMenu(title: "MainMenu")
        
        let mainMenuItem0 = NSMenuItem(title: "About", action: #selector(NSApplication.about), keyEquivalent: "a")
        mainMenuItem0.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        let mainMenuItem1 = NSMenuItem(title: "Close", action: #selector(NSWindow.performClose(_:)), keyEquivalent: "w")
        mainMenuItem1.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        let mainMenuItem2 = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApplication.shared.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q")
        mainMenuItem2.keyEquivalentModifierMask = .command
        
        mainMenu.submenu?.items = [mainMenuItem0, mainMenuItem1, mainMenuItem2]
        appMainMenu.items = [mainMenu]
        
        NSApp.mainMenu = appMainMenu
        
    }
    
}


extension NSApplication {
    @objc func about() {
        AboutView().openInWindow(title: "About My App", sender: self)
    }
}

struct AboutView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.green
            .frame(width: 500, height: 200)
    }
}

extension View {
    @discardableResult
    func openInWindow(title: String, sender: Any?) -> NSWindow {
        
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.center()
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: self)
        window.title = title
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)
        return window
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there more error details in the console?

Comment: No just that one, and it does not help me to find the issue.

Comment: What the windows's value of [`isReleasedWhenClosed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419062-isreleasedwhenclosed)?

Comment: I have no more codes to show, that is all I got. Should I set some value for window when I am creating it in extention?

Comment: @Milen I'm asking you to check the value of that property of your NSWindow in the debugger

Comment: I checked it in deinit about it, and the value was false.

Comment: let released = window.isReleasedWhenClosed returns true in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line of code fixes it: **window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false** added to the function openInWindow().  Reference is here:https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651592  .  Your original code would destroy the about window object each time it was opened and closed.  By not allowing it to do that your code runs without error. Make this substitution.

```
extension View {
    @discardableResult
    func openInWindow(title: String, sender: Any?) -> NSWindow {
        
        let window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.center()
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: self)
        window.title = title
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)
        return window
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the about window should be a SwiftUI view. Also there is other windows as well that needs a custom swiftui, your answer should take a swiftUI view as about view.

Comment: See revision of answer.